# Is there a way to make the span go to the center of document

Tags: html, css, text-align

Is there a way you can make the span tag move into the center using CSS?

I need to ask this question because whenever I put text-align in the span, it doesn't work.

```css
span {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is span.
</span>
```

Comment: replace your `<span>` with a `<div>`. By default, span is an ***inline element*** but you want the behaviour of a ***block level element***, which `div` is by default.

Comment: I want to use to span for personal reasons instead of a div.

Comment: I think div is also a great option for other projects I am creating so I am going to use that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add display block:

```
span {
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, is that for a splash screen ?

- flex

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is span.
</span>
```

- grid

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is span.
</span>
```

and before flex there was :

- table display:

```css
html {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is span.
</span>
```

and before display:table there was also  :

- inline-block and a pseudo:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is span.
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

span tag is an inline element so you can **set `display: inline-block` and `width`**

```css
span {
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<span>
This is span.
</span>
```

or you can **wrap it around with a block element**:

```css
div {
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>
This is span.
</span>
</div>
```

or **use flexbox**

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<span>
this is a span
</span>
```

and see [inline_elemets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

Comment: This also helps too and I think I can use all three options for various reasons.

Comment: @sur yes, I think so too. you can use inline-block when you need `span` tag to be inline but set width or something.  
and you can use flex when you need to align things easily.
and you can wrap it around with a block element when you need other things to be aligned too.

Answer (score 2):

span is an inline tag.  If you want it to be centered, it needs to be in a block element.

e.g.

```
<p><span>This is span</span></p>
```

CSS

```
p { text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `span` is an inline element. This means that when it contains a text it takes the text width, not full width. You can put it in a `div` parent and give the div `text-align: center` and you can give it `display:inline-block` and set the width to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

try using a div

```
<body>
<style>
    #stackoverflow{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<div id="stackoverflow">
    <span>
        Test
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center your span in the whole screen, use CSS `Flexbox` to do this, wrap your span in a div:

```
<div>
  <p><span>This is span.</span></p>
</div>
```

Apply this CSS

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Use span in a `<p>` not seprately.